# How to select <rb>, <rt>, and <rp> text?

Tags: html, css

When I have

```
<ruby><rb>文本</rb><rp>（</rp><rt>wen ben</rt><rp>）</rp></ruby>文本文本
```

or

```
<ruby><rb>文本</rb><rp>（</rp><rt>wen ben</rt><rp>）</rp></ruby>

文本文本
```

And I select both the `<ruby>` text and the regular text outside the `<ruby>` tags, only the `<rb>` surrounded text is selected, but not `<rt>` or `<rp>` text. How can I select `<rb>`, `<rt>`, and `<rp>` text, along with text outside the `<ruby>` tags?

I tried CSS

```
ruby, rt, rp {
    user-select: all;
}
```

```
ruby > rp,
ruby > rt {
    user-select: all;
}
```

```
user-select: text;
```

And HTML `<div style = 'user-select'>` `<span style = 'user-select'>` outside and inside the `<ruby>` tags. (Inside caused weird `<rt>` behavior.)

Nothing seemed to work.